# Subtracting two arrays from each other, but one repeating periodically?

Tags: arrays, c, function, clion

I got stuck with the following array management task in C, could you help me? Below is the code I have written so far.

ESA astronomers received a special radio signal from around the world. The signal, on the other hand, is a known natural radio source,
it comes from the direction of a neutron star, so the two signals are mixed. Fortunately, the star has been watched for a long time,
so they know exactly what periodic signal it emits. Astronomers should be separated
the known periodic signal of a neutron star from the unknown signal.
The captured signal, as well as the neutron star signal, is used by astronomers' digitizing machines for non-negative integers.
converted into a series of numbers. The difference between the two series will be the digitized version of the particular radio signal.
Write a function that clears the noisy signal from the known signal of the neutron star. The function gets three arrays as parameters. The first two are the noisy signal and the star radio signal. Both are non-negative numbers
sequence, which is closed by the value -1 (which, in turn, is no longer part of the series, only closes it). The noisy signal
not shorter than the sign of the star. The latter contains only one period the star is constantly repeating
from its radio signal. The third parameter of the function is also an array into which the pure radio signal must be generated.
set by subtracting the element with the same sequence number from the given element of the noisy array. (If
if the star runs out during the array, we will reuse its elements from the beginning as many times as
required.) The clear signal will also contain only non-negative values ​​(this does not need to be checked separately),
and the clean array must also be closed with a value of -1. (The length will be the same as the noisy array.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void jeltisztitas(int noisy[], int star[], int clean[]) {

    int j = 0;

    if(j <= 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof noisy -1 / sizeof noisy[0]; i++, j++) {
            A:
            clean[i] = noisy[i] - star[j];
            if (j >= 3) {
                j = 0;
                goto A;
                }
            }   int k = sizeof noisy -1;
                clean[k] = '\0';
        }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof noisy -1 / sizeof noisy[0]` is very suspicious, `sizeof noisy` is the size of a pointer, not the number of elements of the array (same for `int k = sizeof noisy -1;`)

Comment: I could use this to get the number of pieces for the array, and the second one to get the last element, because I have to set it to \ 0 so that the larger array is not full of garbage. Or don't I think well?

Answer (score 1):

I think a little bit of modulo math is all you need to solve this reptition issue. Consider a simple example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int b[] = {1, 2, 3};

    size_t len_a = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    size_t len_b = sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < len_a; i++) {
        size_t i_b = i % len_b;

        printf("%d - %d = %d\n", a[i], b[i_b], a[i] - b[i_b]);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1 - 1 = 0
2 - 2 = 0
3 - 3 = 0
4 - 1 = 3
5 - 2 = 3
6 - 3 = 3
7 - 1 = 6
```

We accomplish this by getting the remainder of the index `i` when divided by the length of the shorter array. In the above case, the maximum index of `b` is `2`, so when the index `i` reaches `3`, `3 % 3` is `0`. This pattern will repeat any number of times.